# focus and type into input field when typing outside the input field with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

as the title states, i want to type into the input field when im typing outside the input field.
with the current code i can get focus on the input field when im typing outside, but cant seem to get the key i pressed appear on it. pls help..

like on [google.com](http://google.com) when you are typing without focusing the input field.

```
<form id="searchForm" name="search">
<input id="searchBox" name="search_text">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $("body").on("keyup", function(e) {
            $("#searchForm[name='search_text']").focus();
        });
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean typing outside... check if you get anything in your keyup event...`console.log(e.which)`

Comment: i just want to get focus on the input field and the key i pressed be put into the input field when im typng outside the input field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with only Javascript (there's no need for jQuery):

```
function inputFocus(){
   document.getElementById("searchBox").focus();
}
   window.onkeydown = inputFocus;
```

See [**the working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kmuq1rc5/1/).

Comment: well, still same result as my code.. i need a way to get the key i pressed when not in focus of the input field to get in the field life on google.com

Comment: Do you want the inputted value to be forwarded to the google.com search input??

Comment: want the inputted value to appear on the input field (when not in focus of the input field).. like on google.com when you type after you lost focus of the search box.

Comment: @Light93: well then it's so simple, just change the `onkeyup` to `onkeydown`, see my [EDIT](http://jsfiddle.net/kmuq1rc5/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this example:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#searchBox").focus();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="searchForm" name="search">
  <input id="searchBox" name="search_text">
</form>
```

Comment: nope. still the same result. only getting focus on the input field. the key i pressed is lost, i need it to appear on the field

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<style>
body, div, input {
   color: #afa;
   text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
}
<style>
<input id="searchBox" name="search_text" style="color: transparent">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("body").on("keyup", function(e) {
        $("#searchBox").focus();
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: that only helps to get focus on the field on page load time.. need something to help me type into the field when i have no focus of it